# Creating filters in EmberJS - Concept

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need some ideas on how to create a search filter in EmberJS where the search results can persist across views. Lets say I have a list of contacts and I filtered the list. Assume this route is called `Contacts/Index`

Now I have a second route called `Contacts/Details`. The user will be directed to this route once they select a result from the contact list. Now when they click 'Back To Contacts', I want the previous filter to be still applied instead of showing all the Contacts.

I didn't write any code yet, so I can't provide a JSFiddle. All I can think of now is probably to create a global variable to keep track of the text that is used to filter and apply that when transitioning back to the `Contacts/Index` view but I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just pseudo-code that doesn't really care what your filter type is, but you could apply a filter property to the `ContactsIndexController`:

```
App.ContactsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  //...
  filter: 'name=bro',
  filteredContent: function () {
    if(this.get('filter')){
      return this.get('content').filter//...;
    } else {
      return this.get('content');
    }
  }.property('filter')
  //...//
});
```

Whenever you change the filter, make sure to update the `filter` property:

```
this.set('filter', 'foo=bar');
```

Then in your handlebars template you always loop over `filteredContent`:

```
{{#each filteredContent}}
{{/each}}
```

When you transition back and forth between the `Contacts` inner routes, it should retain the filter when you return to the index.

You can also see how this pattern could be used to take this one step further and manipulate the filter from literally anywhere in the application. If you aren't in that controller's context, you can still update that property and bindings will appropriately render the computed property next time you visit.

From another controller:

`this.set('controllers.contacts-index.filter', 'year=20x6')`

From a route:

`this.controllerFor('contacts-index').set('filter', 'year=20x6')`

From a view within the index controller:

`this.set('controller.filter', 'year=20x6')`

I'm sure you get the idea.

This is, of course, one of several approaches you could take. I prefer this particular pattern.

Hope that helps and good luck!

Comment: That's awesome Matthew. Thanks for the concept. Much appreciated.